# C# project targeting .NET 4.5.1 is unavailable in VS 2013 (Windows 8.1 with .NET 4.6 is installed)

Tags: .net, windows-8.1

I had a solution containing several ASP.NET MVC projects, targeting .NET 4.5.1 . When I open them in VS2013, it's showing as unavailable and when I try to reload it, there is an error :

> The C# project `ABC` is targeting ".NETFramework, Version=v4.5", which
>   is not installed on this machine. To proceed, select an option below:

then it gives options to change target framework, or download the targeting pack, or do not load.

When I chose to download and install .NET 4.5.1 targeting VS2013, the installer popup this message: "A newer .NET version is already installed".

How do I reinstall .NET 4.5.1 when .NET 4.6 is there ? I tried to look for .NET 4.6 to uninstall in `Programs & Features` but there is none.

NOte: 
FYI I had VS2015 installed as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should download the Targeting Pack, not the Runtime,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet_sdks.aspx